# Is it possible to solve this problem without x-axis and y-axis?

Tags: geometry, vectors

[image: Vector]

Is it possible to solve this problem without x-axis and y-axis ?
And If it is, What is the way to solve it?

Comment: I think you may have forgotten to include your problem :)

Comment: Ok, now that you added the problem, you might want to elaborate on what you're thinking as to convince people not to downvote your question: what makes you think you would need the $x$ and $y$ axes, and how would they help you solve the problem?

Comment: I'm asking about x-axis and y-axis because by them i can get the coordinates of A ,B and C and After that I can easily calculate the answer

Comment: As @greenbagels said, please do elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Yes, it is possible to solve this problem without defining coordinates. Here is a link that will be of use to you: [adding and subtracting vectors geometrically](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/adding-and-subtracting-vectors)

Comment: OK, but here he's asking for a norm 
I wanna know how can i solve it without coordinates?

Comment: After you geometrically add and subtract vectors, you will be left with a vector $v=A+B-C$ on the plane. Then use the Pythagorean Theorem to calculate the norm of $v$.

Comment: In this problem, you won't even need to use the Pythagorean Theorem because your final vector will be a vertical line, so just count how many units long it is.

Comment: Can you clarify please

Comment: I have included a picture so that you can visualize the steps we need to take.

Answer (score 1):

We don't need axis, the grid is sufficient, as we may add vectors geometrically - by moving them into positions, where the end point of the first vector coincides with the start point of the second one:

[image]

Substacting the vector $\overrightarrow C$ is the same as adding the vector $-\overrightarrow C.$

The grid shows us that $\left\lVert \overrightarrow A + \overrightarrow B - \overrightarrow C \right\rVert = 5$ , i. e. the $(c)$ variant of your task is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Coordinates of a vector don't depend from the *absolute* positions of its start and end point, but only by the position of its end point *relative to* its start point.

Formally,

$$\overrightarrow {XY} = Y - X$$

i. e. if $X=(x_1, x_2)\ $ and $\ Y = (y_1, y_2)$, then

$$\overrightarrow {XY} = (y_1-x_1, \;y_2-x_2)$$

Informally, we obtain coordinates of the vector as horizontal and vertical distance from X to Y:

[image]

So we don't need the axes, because from you picture we see that

\begin{align}
\overrightarrow {A} &= (3, 0)\\
\overrightarrow {B} &= (1, -3)\\
\overrightarrow {C} &= (4, 2)
\end{align}

so

$$\left\lVert \overrightarrow A + \overrightarrow B - \overrightarrow C \right\rVert = \left\lVert (3, 0) + (1, -3) - (4, 2) \right\rVert  = \left\lVert (0, -5) \right\rVert = 5$$